# How to save the resulting data of matplotlib imshow()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote the following code to visualize the intensity of matrix a as a heatmap.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random((16, 16))
plt.imshow(a, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

Is there a way to save the resulting data of `plt.imshow(a, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')` as a ndarray (i.e., [16, 16, 3] matrix)? Thanks!

Comment: @Phineas imshow and show are different.

Comment: Thanks, @Phineas. Actually the problem is different. I want to save the result of plt.imshow(a, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest') as a numpy array because I want to use it for further computation. Thanks...

Comment: Thanks. I know that. So if I want to get the result as a ndarray, I have to save it to file and then read it out, right? Is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Ohh do you want to save the data of the plot and not the plot itself?

Comment: Yes, correct. @Phineas

Comment: Ok. Try putting the results of plt.imshow() in a variable, say a. Then try a._A or a.get_array() or a.set_array(data). What are your results?

Comment: The results is (16 x 16) matrix. This is implausible since the heat map should include RGB channels. The correct result should be (16 x 16 x 3).

Comment: Please edit your question so that people understand that you need the data and not the plot image!

Comment: Hey! Did you find a solution to your question? If yes please share it :)